# Excel function IF combination produces "You've entered too many arguments for this function" error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft

Could anyone help me fix this issue?
I tried to make this Excel formula work, however, I got the error stating 'You've entered too many arguments for this function"

Should I use a different excel function such as =IF(AND?

This is what the formula currently looks like

=IF(ISBLANK(Q2); IF(TODAY()>R2;"Overdue";IF(TODAY()+14>=R2;"Due within two weeks";"On time"));IF(Q2>R2;"Overdue";"On time");IF(TODAY()+14>=R2;"Due within two weeks";"On time"))IF(Q2>R2;"Overdue";"On time"))

I tried to use this IF(AND formula

=IF(AND(ISBLANK(Q2);IF(TODAY()>R2;"Overdue";IF(TODAY()+7>=R2;"Due within a week";"On time"));IF(TODAY()>R2;"Overdue";IF(TODAY()+14>=R2;"Due within a week";"On time"));IF(Q2>R2;"Overdue";"On time"))

but then I get an error stating this formula is missing an opening and closing parenthesis

Thank you!

Comment: The nesting in your formula isn't correct. It goes wrong after `IF(Q2>R2;"Overdue";"On time");` where you close the IF and continue with  a fourth argument for `IF(ISBLANK(Q2)...`. And the last `IF(Q2>R2...)` doesn't belong to anything.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=you%27ve+entered+too+many+arguments+for+this+function This has been asked a LOT of times before.

Comment: It seems your formula is too complicated for such a simple task. You want to get one of three string values in a calculated cell. These values are calculated in increments of 7 days relative to the announced date in Q2 and the expected date in R2 (if the Q2 cell does not contain a value, then the current date is used for calculations). Did I understand the logic of your formula correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Let's rebuild your formula together, step by step.

Getting one of the three rows is easiest using the [**CHOOSE() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc)

`=CHOOSE(<Value 1-3>;"On time";"Due within a week";"Overdue")`

Now let's look at the dates in the Q column. If the cell in Q2 does not contain a value, then you need to use the current date, otherwise use this value. This is easily written using the [**IF() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

`IF(ISBLANK(Q2);TODAY();Q2)`

Subtract from the value of R2 the result of the resulting `IF()` function and another 1. Subtracting one will equalize the result of comparing dates (if the date in Q2 is exactly equal to the date in R2, then we will get **-1**). We divide the result of the subtraction by 7, by the number of days in a week, and take the integer part of the division. In addition, we wrap this entire expression in the [**SIGN() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sign-function-109c932d-fcdc-4023-91f1-2dd0e916a1d8).

So we get **-1** for all dates less than or equal to R2, **0** for dates within a week after R2, and **1** for all other dates.

Since the `CHOOSE()` function needs a value from 1 to 3, we will add 2 to the result. The final formula will be:
`=CHOOSE(SIGN(INT((R2-IF(ISBLANK(Q2);TODAY();Q2)-1)/7))+2;"On time";"Due within a week";"Overdue")`

As you can see, the formula is a bit shorter than when using nested `IF()`

Answer (score 0):

Taking your first expression and separating out all the arguments of the `IF()` functions, it looks like this

```
=IF (                                                01   Opening bracket of outermost IF
     ISBLANK(Q2);                                    02   Argument 1
     IF (                                            03   Argument 2 starts
         TODAY()>R2;                                 04
         "Overdue";                                  05
         IF (                                        06
             TODAY()+14>=R2;                         07
             "Due within two weeks";                 08
             "On time"                               09
            )                                        10
        );                                           11   Argument 2 ends
     IF (                                            12   Argument 3 starts
         Q2>R2;                                      13
         "Overdue";                                  14
         "On time"                                   15
        );                                           16   Argument 3 ends
     IF (                                            17   Argument 4(!) starts
         TODAY()+14>=R2;                             18
         "Due within two weeks";                     19
         "On time"                                   20
        )                                            21   Argument 4 ends 
    )                                                22   Closing bracket of outermost IF
                                                     23    
IF (                                                 24   No operator joining to  lines 01 to 22
    Q2>R2;                                           25
    "Overdue";                                       26
    "On time"                                        27
   )                                                 28
)                                                    29
```

The outermost `IF`, including its opening left bracket is on line 01. It should have 3 arguments - *condition*, *value if condition is true* and *value if condition is false*. The first of these arguments is on line 02. The second argument is itself an `IF()` function and occupies lines 03 to 11 inclusive. The third argument, also an `IF()` function, occupies lines 12 to 16 inclusive.

The third argument should mark the end of the outermost `IF`, but it doesn't. Instead, lines 17 to 21 inclusive attempt to add a fourth argument to the outermost `IF()` and the closing right bracket.

So attempting to write an `IF()` function with 4 arguments explains the error message '*You've entered too many arguments for this function*'

Unfortunately, this is not the only issue with your first expression. There are two others.

First, the closing right bracket on line 22 is followed by a second outermost `IF` on line 24 (I inserted a blank line as line 23 to emphasise that the first outermost `IF` had ended). Whilst it is possible to have a formula with two unnested functions these need to be linked together, typically using an operator.

For example

```
=IF(A1>0;"Positive";"Negative")&IF(B1="Measured";" Reading";" Estimate")
```

combines the results of two `IF()` functions using the `&` operator.

Second, line 29 contains an unmatched closing bracket.

So what should your expression actually look like?

It seems that you are trying to compare two dates: the second of these is in cell `R2` and the first is possibly in cell `Q2` - though if `Q2` is a blank cell you use `TODAY()` as the first date. Other than that: you want to deliver the following results:

- "Overdue" - whenever first date is after the second
- "Due within two weeks" - whenever first date is not after second, but second date is within 14 days of first
- "On time" - otherwise

There are a variety of ways you can approach this: here are a few variations on a theme

**Method 1 - Helper cell**

Assign a helper cell (say `S2`) with the first date using the formula: `=IF(ISBLANK(Q2);TODAY();Q2)`
Then use a couple nested `IF`'s to compare values in `R2`and `S2` to get the correct result using the formula `=IF(S2>R2;"Overdue";IF(S2+14>=R2;"Due within two weeks";"On time"))`

**Method 2 - Repeated phrase**

Instead of using the helper cell, repeat its formula in a larger formula:
`=IF(IF(ISBLANK(Q2);TODAY();Q2)>R2;"Overdue";IF(IF(ISBLANK(Q2);TODAY();Q2)+14>=R2;"Due within two weeks";"On time"))`

**Method 3 - Use the LET() function to define the first date**

`=LET(firstdate;IF(ISBLANK(Q2);TODAY();Q2);IF(firstdate>R2;"Overdue";IF(firstdate+14>=R2;"Due within 2 weeks";"On time")))`

**Method 4 -Possibly what you intended originally**

`=IF(ISBLANK(Q2);IF(TODAY()>R2;"Overdue";IF(TODAY()+14>=R2;"Due within two weeks";"On time"));IF(Q2>R2;"Overdue";IF(Q2+14>=R2;"Due within two weeks";"On time")))`

Method 1 is simple but sometimes constructors of worksheets have an aversion to keeping things simple. Method 2 is clunky and, in my view, it is poor practice to repeat phrases within a formula. Method 3 is, arguably, Microsoft's attempt to pander to the non-simplists who dislike Method 1 and at the same time avoid the clunkiness of Method 2. To use Method 3 you will need either the Office 365 or Office 21 version of Excel.

Method 4, like Method 2, is also repetitious, though the repetition in Method 4 is a bit more subtle. The second and third arguments of the outermost `IF()` of Method 4 are the same except the second argument uses `TODAY()` whilst the third replaces this with `Q2`.

Repetition in a formula is generally not a good idea, since any corrections/modifications to a repeated part have to be applied more than once.